# Interpretation of p-values in linear mixed model with collinearity

Tags: r, mixed-model, multicollinearity

Imagine I am looking for the association between test score and whether eating candy (candy Yes or No) before taking the tests. I randomly select students from 8 random schools (A,B,C...H). Here is the plot of the data (Figure 1):

```
set.seed(2)
candy<-c(rep("No",200),rep("Yes", 200))
school<-c(rep("A",90),rep("B",90),rep("C",10),rep("D",10),rep("E",10),rep("F",10),rep("G",90),rep("H",90))
test_score<-c(rnorm(90,10,3),rnorm(90,20,3),rnorm(10,30,1),rnorm(10,40,1),rnorm(10,10,1),rnorm(10,20,1),rnorm(90,30,3),rnorm(90,40,3))
dat<-data.frame(Candy=candy,School=school,Test.score=test_score)
dat<-dat[sample(1:nrow(dat),nrow(dat), replace = F),]
dat$Candy=relevel(factor(dat$Candy), ref="No")
dat$School=relevel(factor(dat$School), ref="A")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = Candy, y = Test.score, color = School))+geom_jitter(width = 0.1)
```

Figure 1:
[image]

In this case we can fit both fixed and mixed effect model:

fixed:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Test.score ~ 1 + Candy + School, data = dat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.5550 -1.9357 -0.1078  1.9459  8.2708 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   9.9478     0.3140   31.68   <2e-16 ***
CandyYes     31.0471     0.4440   69.92   <2e-16 ***
SchoolB      10.2638     0.4440   23.12   <2e-16 ***
SchoolC      19.9601     0.9928   20.10   <2e-16 ***
SchoolD      29.6515     0.9928   29.86   <2e-16 ***
SchoolE     -30.7805     0.9928  -31.00   <2e-16 ***
SchoolF     -20.8068     0.9928  -20.96   <2e-16 ***
SchoolG     -10.6004     0.4440  -23.87   <2e-16 ***
SchoolH           NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.979 on 392 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9383,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9371 
F-statistic: 850.9 on 7 and 392 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

mixed:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Test.score ~ 1 + Candy + (1 | School)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 2045.9

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.87125 -0.64684 -0.03427  0.65381  2.77778 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 School   (Intercept) 168.284  12.972  
 Residual               8.872   2.979  
Number of obs: 400, groups:  School, 8

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  24.8937     6.4957  6.0002   3.832  0.00863 **
CandyYes      0.5782     9.1863  6.0002   0.063  0.95186   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr)
CandyYes -0.707
```

We can see the the p-values are very different in these two models. Looks like the fixed effect model is telling us test score is associated with both candy and school. However the mixed effect model is telling us test score is not associated with candy. Now I have some questions:

1. how to explain the discrepancy between two models? which model should we use and why?
2. which model is testing if test score is associated with candy WITHIN each school?
3. There is a collinearity between candy and school. As we can see students in school A-D did not receive candy whereas students E-H always received candy. Fixed model needs to drop one school to avoid complete linear dependency however mixed effect model does not need to do it. Then how does mixed effect model handle collinearity? why is collinearity in mixed model less problematic compared to fixed model?
4. is test score associated with candy? can we tell from this experimental design? by the way, changing the mean of each school can make p-value of candy in mixed model stronger (Figure 2). how to explain this? In this case is p-value trustworthy if someone thinks overall the experimental design is incorrect?

Figure 2:
[image]

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Test.score ~ 1 + Candy + (1 | School)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 2043.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.87067 -0.64499 -0.03808  0.65428  2.77837 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 School   (Intercept) 104.539  10.224  
 Residual               8.872   2.979  
Number of obs: 400, groups:  School, 8

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error     df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)    7.649      5.124  6.000   1.493    0.186  
CandyYes      17.837      7.247  6.000   2.461    0.049 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr)
CandyYes -0.707
```

These might be naive questions. However I have not found any questions similar to this. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: In your data set has eating candy nested in the school.  The population with the school is homogenous they either all ate candy or they didn't.   You can separate out the effect from each other.  The linear model is just calculating the mean of each school referenced to school A, this is not the correct model to use.

Comment: Hello, @Dave2e , thank you so much for your answer! In your answer, did you mean "you CANNOT separate out the effect from each other"? And which linear model is not correct? the fixed model or mixed model? If I want to test if eating candy is associated with test score, which model should I run?

Comment: Correct, "Cannot".  Auto correct gets me too often.  Yes the fix model is just predicting the mean for each school/candy combination.  I would go with the mixed model.  I don't understand what the difference is between the 2nd and 3rd mix models.  I would go with the 3rd model.

Comment: Thank you @Dave2e, thank you for your message. 2nd and 3rd models are the same except the data is different. the 3rd model is for Figure 2. I label them more clearly now the in original answer.